# Alternating background colors for columns in a table?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm working on putting alternating background color for columns in a table, and I have one working CSS code for a pretty simple table.

But when it gets a little bit complicated (with rowspan / colspan) my CSS code fails. Can someone help me here please? Guide me to which direction I should take to fix it?

The table codes I'm working on are all generated by someone else and I have no control over it. The tables they would make are all valid HTML codes, the CSS I need to make should work on them.

You can see my working / failing CSS code here:

http://www.cssdesk.com/u7ZUu

or

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORPLgz

```
table.specialtable {
  border-top: 2px solid #00ABEF;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00ABEF;
    background-colo: #FFF;
    font-size: 11px;
}

table.specialtable th {
    background-color: #B8E5FA;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
    padding: 4px 2px;
}

table.specialtable td {
    padding: 4px 2px;
    text-align: center;
}

table.specialtable td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}

table.specialtable td:nth-child(even){ 
 background-color: #E2F4FE;
}

table.specialtable td:nth-child(odd){ 
 background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: have a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26816051/color-first-column-when-there-is-rowspan-in-html-table

Answer (score 1):

this is kinda crazy markup but it does what you're looking for. I got rid off some useless over specificity while at it, and I'm using SCSS, hope you don't mind.

I forked your pen here: http://codepen.io/memoblue/pen/yayBpA

Here's the relevant code:

```
table {
  border-top: 2px solid #00ABEF;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00ABEF;
    background-colo: #FFF;
    font-size: 11px;
}

table th {
    background-color: #B8E5FA;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
    padding: 4px 2px;
}

table td {
    padding: 4px 2px;
    text-align: center;
}

table td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}

table td:nth-child(even){ 
 background-color: #E2F4FE;
}

table td:nth-child(odd){ 
 background-color: #FFF;
}

.specialtable ~ table {
  tr:nth-child(2n) {
    td:first-child {
      background-color: #E2F4FE;
    }
    td:nth-child(2n) {
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    &:nth-child(8) {
      td:first-child {
        background-color: #fff;
      }
    }
  }
}
```